# How to show array data to each section and rows in table view swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, uikit, tableview

i want to present array of data that sent from previous page.
one array consists of several data and I want to put each array in one section.
The data of each array will be listed in rows of each section.
the example of the array looks like this:

```
[WS.LicenseData(stdLicense: 8, dcLicense: 0, userCALlicense: 2, rdsCALlicense: 2, stdPrice: 80000000, dcPrice: 0, userCALprice: 20000000, rdsCALprice: 20000000, totalServerPrice: 120000000), 
WS.LicenseData(stdLicense: 0, dcLicense: 8, userCALlicense: 1, rdsCALlicense: 1, stdPrice: 0, dcPrice: 80000000, userCALprice: 10000000, rdsCALprice: 10000000, totalServerPrice: 100000000)]
```

Here's the expected outcome of the table view (that's for each section)

[image]

Next, the data is sent from previous page.
I want to list the data from each array into table view rows, but I can't.
I had this error saying that the index is out of range.
My guess is because my array is still empty.
But if I use `for loop`, it only read the last array and it's not working.
take a look at my code:

```
var licenseResultArray = [LicenseData]()

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return licenseResultArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: LicenseResultTVCell.cellIdentifier) as! LicenseResultTVCell
    let arrayLicenseResult = licenseResultArray[indexPath.row]
    let resultStd = arrayLicenseResult.stdLicense
    let resultDc = arrayLicenseResult.dcLicense
    
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.labelTitleServer.text = "Total Server \(indexPath.section + 1)"
        if resultStd != 0 && resultDc == 0 {
            print("license type = std")
            cell.labelTitleServer.text = "License Type = Standard"
        }
        
        else if resultStd == 0 && resultDc != 0 {
            print("license type = dc")
            cell.labelTitleServer.text = "License Type = Datacenter"
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

I hope y'all get what I mean, if you need me to elaborate more, feel free to comment.
Any help will be appreciated, thankyou in advance!

Comment: You take about arrays in plural and about using sections but in your code you have only one array and are not working with any sections so it's hard to understand what your issue is.

Comment: please check my edited code. thanks

Comment: It’s still hard to understand what you are trying to do, do you really have multiple arrays or is it just one? I get the impression you have your own idea what a section is but I don’t really get this idea. Some issues, in numberOfSections you return the count of licenseResultArray but in cellForRowAt you do licenseResultArray[indexPath.row] and this is inconsistent since it then should be licenseResultArray[indexPath.section] to first get the array for that section and in a next step the item for the row. Also hard coding the result of numbersOfRowsInSection looks incorrect.

Comment: hey man, you actually just gave me the answer! sorry I couldn't explain it best to you, but your confusion gave me a straight answer. thankyou for that. I have a question tho when u said " hard coding the result of numbersOfRowsInSection looks incorrect ". The thing is, I want to return it 5. but yes, i know it's hard coded. So what's the best practice to fix this stuff? Thankyou in advance